# In Vxworks is there any API which returns total number of file descriptors created?

Tags: vxworks

In vxworks is there any API which returns total number of file descriptors created in system?.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this would be helpful.

```
int number_of_opened_fd()
{
    int fd;
    int count = 0;

    for (fd=3; fd<iosFdMaxFiles(); fd++) {
        if (iosFdMap(fd) != NULL) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

If you want to increase max fd,

```
$ vxprj parameter set NUM_FILES 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no API call which is doing that. I've had some problems with file descriptors a few years ago and I didn't find any. So I've used something like the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <config/all/configAll.h>   /* NUM_FILES */

int getUsedFds(void)
{
    FILE *fd[1024];     /* just some big number */
    int count;
    int free;
    int used;


    /* get all remaining file descriptors... */
    for (count = 0; count < 1024; count++)
    {
        fd[count] = fopen("/tffs0/some_existing_file", "r");
        if (fd[count] == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    free = count;
    used = NUM_FILES - free;   /* NUM_FILES is a VxWorks configuration value */
                               /* Usually NUM_FILES is about 25-60 */   

    /* clean up the mess we've made! */
    for (count--; count >= 0; count--)
    {
        fclose(fd[count]);
    }

    return (used);
}
```

If you don't want to open existing files I think you can create sockets as well. As far as I remember sockets are implemented using file descriptors.

If you have not enough file descriptors available you can increase the maximum number of file descriptors of your VxWorks...